# R : Find combinations of columns which match specified result

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with hundreds of lines and 10s of columns, and need to find the rows, which sum is within a range. I searched for permutations and computations and subset sum problem, but none of the provided solutions seem to match the desired result.

Please advice me, whether there exists a package that solves such problem. 
Is there a function or any vectorised way to solve these kind of "iterations" in R?

```
# sample dataframe
x <- data.frame(a=c("A","B","C","D"),b=c(1,2,1,1))
```

Let assume, the sum of any accepted combination is 3, then the desired result could be a list like

```
[[1]]     # combination 1
[1] 
1,2       # lists all rows used
[2]  
1,2      # lists all values use

[[2]]     # combination 2
[1]       
2,1       # lists all rows used
[2]
2,1       # lists all values used

[[3]]     # combination 3
[1]       
2,4       # lists all rows used
[2]       
2,1       # lists all values used

[[4]]     # combination 4
[1]
1,3,4     # lists all rows used
[2]       
1,1,1     # lists all values used
```

(# comments: these are only added for explanatory purposes)

Note:

1. not all possible combinations are required, and not all values have
   to be used!
2. a row must only be used ONCE in a given combination (i.e. summing 3 times row one is no option!)
3. combinations could be `sum(x[1:2,2])` as well as `(x[1,2] x[2,2]+ .... + x[n,2]))`

Comment: Are you trying to sum by column, or can a sum include values from other columns as well?

Comment: Please, only sum values within one column; not values from aller columns. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understand your question correctly. But, supposing we have some matrix `dat`, we wish to sum up (for each column) the different combinations of rows. We can accomplish this using the `*apply` family of functions, along with `combn`.

Here's what we do:

1. Loop over the columns of our matrix (using `apply`)
2. For each column of our matrix, sum up the unique combinations of rows (using `lapply` and `apply`)
3. We generate the unique combinations using the `combn` function within an `sapply` call

#### generate sample `dat`

```
set.seed(123)
dat <- matrix(rnorm(5 * 6), nrow = 5, ncol = 6)
```

#### loop through each column of `dat`

```
big_list <- apply(dat, 2, FUN = function(matcol) # over the columns of dat
  lapply(sapply(1:5, FUN = function(x) combn(1:5, x)), # loop through unique combinations of rows in dat
         FUN = function(combs) 
           apply(combs, 2, #over the columns of unique combinations
                 FUN = function(rows) 
                   data.frame(
                     'rows_used' = paste(rows, collapse = ', '), 
                     'n_rows' = length(rows), 
                     'sum' = sum(matcol[rows]))))) #sum up the rows

[[1]] # column 
[[1]][[1]] #[[n_rows]][[n_comb]]
  rows_used n_rows        sum
1         1      1 -0.5604756

[[1]][[2]]
  rows_used n_rows        sum
1         2      1 -0.2301775

[[1]][[3]]
  rows_used n_rows      sum
1         3      1 1.558708
```

After we've gone through each column and each combination of rows, we can extract the data from the `list` into a `data.frame`. Suppose, for example, we were interested in the sums from column 6:

#### Using the results

```
column <- 6
df_from_list <- do.call('rbind',
        lapply(big_list[[column]], 
                 FUN = function(x) do.call('rbind', x)))

       rows_used n_rows        sum
1              1      1 -1.6866933
2              2      1  0.8377870
3              3      1  0.1533731
4              4      1 -1.1381369
5              5      1  1.2538149
```

Then, we can use the `subset` function (or `dplyr::filter`) to get all combinations of n rows in column 6 where the sum is >= 0 and <= 0.5:

```
subset(df_from_list, sum >= 0 & sum <= .5)

   rows_used n_rows       sum
3          3      1 0.1533731
15      4, 5      2 0.1156780
18   1, 2, 5      3 0.4049087
25   3, 4, 5      3 0.2690511
```

#### Side note

It wouldn't surprise if this calculation method doesn't scale well, and I'm sure there is a more efficient solution. The structure of the problem as I've solved it results in a nested `list` structure, meaning a user should be familiar with the `list` object in `R`.

Comment: First of all: Thanks a million! It sound like what I need. Alas, may I ask for some help with the output: how could I find in the resulting list for example all combination where the sum of n rows of Column 6 is greater than 0 but smaller than 0.5?

Comment: I have edited my solution to show how we might be able to use the results from the calculation. Note that I changed how we calculate the list slightly. Mainly, we now store the results inside of a `data.frame` inside of the `list`.